# Running Django 1.3 on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Can't get Django 1.3 running with the current GAE helper (from Google). Anyone have the config solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the current 'generally' recommended approach to Django on App Engine is [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), I believe it supports Django 1.3 now.  Check out [Running Pure Django Projects on Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html) for some information on getting started.

Comment: Apparently someone disagrees... why the downvote with no explanation?

Comment: FYI: This answer is not relevant any more.

Answer (score 0):

look at [this](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/app-engine-162-released.html):

App Engine 1.6.2 release notes:

> For Python fans of Google’s Cloud SQL (currently available in limited
>   preview), the long awaited out-of-the-box support for the Django
>   framework has arrived and is now available as an experimental feature.
>   Now you can easily use Cloud SQL within the Django framework as you
>   would use any other SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

[Django 1.3 is now available on all Python runtimes out of the box](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.6.2_-_January_31,_2012)